# Wrangling Attr Dict from Matlab into Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to wrangle an Attr Dict imported from matlab. How do you index into this in python?

[type is mat73.AttrDict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOXOJ.png)

[Overflow error when I try to print the keys in the array. Is there a way to print a subset of keys from Attr Dict?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPzCf.png)